# click event either applies to all or none of li elements

Tags: jquery, html

I am completely new to world of jQuery. I am trying to set animation styles for a div on click event for different `li` elements inside `menu` div.

Please first overview my code, so that I can explain you my problem.

HTML Code:

```
<div id="container">

<div id="outer_div">
<div id="image_div"></div>
<div id="menu">
<ul id="nav">
    <li id="nav1"><a href="">News & Events</a></li>
    <li id="nav2"><a href="">Facilities</a></li>
    <li id="nav3"><a href="">Research</a></li>
    <li id="nav4"><a href="">Programmes</a></li>
    <li id="nav5"><a href="">Faculty</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="popup_menu">
     <ul>
     <li><a href="">abc</a></li>
   <li><a href="">abc</a></li>
   <li><a href="">abc</a></li>
   <li><a href="">abc</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

My jQuery Code is:

```
$(window).load(function(){

$("#popup_menu").fadeIn()
.css({left:-300,position:'absolute',opacity:0})
.animate({left:0,opacity:1.0}, 1000, function() {
//callback
});
});

$("nav1").click(function(){
$("#popup_menu").fadeIn()
.css({left:-300,position:'absolute',opacity:0})
.animate({left:0,opacity:1.0}, 1000, function() {
//callback });

$("nav2").click(function(){
$("#popup_menu").fadeIn()
.css({left:-300,position:'absolute',opacity:0})
.animate({left:0,opacity:1.0}, 1000, function() {
//callback});

 $("nav3").click(function(){
$("#popup_menu").fadeIn()
.css({top:-300,position:'absolute',opacity:0})
.animate({top:0,opacity:1.0}, 1000, function() {
//callback});

$("nav4").click(function(){
$("#popup_menu").fadeIn()
.css({right:-300,position:'absolute',opacity:0})
.animate({right:0,opacity:1.0}, 1000, function() {

$("popup_div").css(right:0);
$("#image_div").css({left:0,top:0});  });

$("nav5").click(function(){
$("#popup_menu").fadeIn()
.css({right:-300,position:'absolute',opacity:0})
.animate({right:0,opacity:1.0}, 1000, function() {
//callback });
});
```

Problem I am facing here is that for all `li` elements, the click event handler `$("nav1").click(function()` is called. *And it is called only when I comment out all other click events for nav2, nav3,nav4,nav5.*

Secondly, my jquery code is not executed if I remove the comments i.e. the above written code.

Can anyone tell me where am I mistaken? I hope my Question is clear... Thanks.

Comment: You have missed `#` for ID selectors. `$('#nav1')`

Comment: I'd suggest visiting this link, and then clicking the 'JS Lint' button, and working through all the reported problems: http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/QJj4q/

Comment: @DavidThomas I have removed all the errors from my code. Thank you all for helping me :) but the weird thing is that I still can't animate div differently on different `li` clicks. My corrected jQuery code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/cKJvZ/

Comment: please anyone there reply. I need to complete it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many corrections as mentioned by people here, I searched here and there for hours and finally got the solution. As I wrote in code above:

```
 $("#nav2").click(function(){
    $("#popup_menu").fadeIn()
    .css({left:-300,position:'absolute',opacity:0})
    .animate({left:0,opacity:1.0}, 1000, function() {
    //callback });
    }
```

There are two mistakes;

1- ID `nav2` not detected and do event was never executed.

2 - This click event is not called on any of the `li` element because no event is attached to it. I needed to attach a "live click event" for individual `li` elements.

So finally solution is:

```
$("#nav li[id='nav2']").live('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
    $("#popup_menu").fadeIn()
.css({left:'-300px',position:'absolute',opacity:0})
.animate({left:'0px',opacity:1.0}, 1000, function() {

});
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You are referencing the `nav1` elements incorrectly, the need a hash symbol (#) to indicate that they are an ID:

```
$("#nav1").click(function(){...
```

Answer (score 2):

You're not closing your `$("#nav[number]").click(function(){` functions. You need the `}` at the end.

```
$("#nav1").click(function(){
    $("#popup_menu").fadeIn()
    .css({left:-300,position:'absolute',opacity:0})
    .animate({left:0,opacity:1.0}, 1000, function() {
    //callback });
}  <-----

$("#nav2").click(function(){
    $("#popup_menu").fadeIn()
    .css({left:-300,position:'absolute',opacity:0})
    .animate({left:0,opacity:1.0}, 1000, function() {
    //callback});
}  <-----

etc...
```

And you also need to reference the id's with '#' e.g. `$("#nav2").click...`

Comment: Yup I missed function ending braces. Thank you for pointing them out :)